# EF Count() > 0 but First() throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have faced a strange problem. When user comes to any page of my web app 
I do check if user has permissions to access it, and provide trial period if its first time to come.

Here is my piece of code:

```
List<string> temp_workers_id = new List<string>();
...
if (temp_workers_id.Count > 6)
                {
                    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sqlDate = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date);    
var rusers = dbctx.tblMappings.Where(tm => temp_workers_id.Any(c => c == tm.ModelID));
    var permissions = dbctx.UserPermissions
       .Where(p => rusers
          .Any(ap => ap.UserID == p.UserID)
             && p.DateStart != null 
             && p.DateEnd != null 
             && p.DateStart <= sqlDate.Value 
             && p.DateEnd >= sqlDate.Value);

    if (permissions.Count() < 1)
    {
       permissions = dbctx.UserPermissions
          .Where(p => rusers
             .Any(ap => ap.UserID == p.UserID) 
                && p.DateStart == null 
                && p.DateEnd == null);

       var used = dbctx.UserPermissions
          .Where(p => rusers
             .Any(ap => ap.UserID == p.UserID) 
                && p.DateStart != null 
                && p.DateEnd != null);

    if (permissions.Count() > 0 && used.Count() < 1)
    {
       var p = permissions.First();
       using (Models.TTTDbContext tdbctx = new Models.TTTDbContext())
       {
              var tp = tdbctx.UserPermissions.SingleOrDefault(tup => tup.UserID == p.UserID);
              tp.DateStart = DateTime.Now.Date;
              tp.DateEnd = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(60);
              tdbctx.SaveChanges();
       }
```

here the `First()` method throws exception:

> Sequence contains no elements

how that even could be?

EDIT:
I dont think that user opens two browsers and navigate here at the same time, but could be the concurrency issue?

Comment: please provide mor code. what is permissions and what is used?

Comment: are you using DefaultIfEmpty in permissions extraction?

Comment: more code added, no DefaultIfEmpty

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt but why Count() > 0 is true?

Comment: Forget that @okarpov, I have misunderstood. Didn't have my coffe yet.

Comment: Is this something reliably reproducible or something that's turned up in logs? Because, of course, you're querying twice, and the underlying database could change state between queries...

Comment: Could it be a race condition? If you don't actually need the full list of permissions, you could include `.FirstOrDefault()` in your query and just check for `null`

Comment: Could be anything, we can't repro this. For all we know, there's another thread modifying `temp_workers_id`. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I thought it could be concurrency problem but I can not even imagine that the same user changes anything twice at the same time

Comment: Can you reproduce it, if you call `permissions = ...Any(...).ToList()`  (Materialize only for debugging)

Comment: data coming to `permissions ` ? Do you checked with debug ? I think you must use `ToList()` method

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt its on server, so I have only log with the exception :(

Comment: "I dont think that user opens two browsers and navigate here at the same time, but could be the concurrency issue?" - here's the problem - we don't know how your application works. Are you saying that this is a check of one users permissions, and *that* user is also the only person capable of editing their own permissions? (That's quite an unusual security model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim you only found this in the server logs and didn't encounter it during debugging. That means that between these lines:

```
if (permissions.Count() > 0)
{
    var p = permissions.First();
```

Some other process or thread changed your database, so that the query didn't match any documents anymore.

This is caused by `permissions` holding a lazily evaluated resource, meaning that the query is only executed when you iterate it (which `Count()` and `First()`) do.

So in the `Count()`, the query is executed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...
```

Which returns, at that moment, one row. Then the data is modified externally, causing the next query (at `First()`):

```
SELECT n1, n2, ... WHERE ...
```

To return zero rows, causing `First()` to throw.

Now for how to solve that, is up to you, and depends entirely on how you want to model this scenario. It means the second query was actually correct: at *that* moment, there were no more rows that fulfilled the query criteria. You could materialize the query once:

```
permissions = query.Where(...).ToList()
```

But that would mean your logic operates on stale data. The same would happen if you'd use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var permissionToApply = permissions.FirstOrDefault();
if (permissionToApply != null)
{
    // rest of your logic
}
```

So it's basically a lose-lose scenario. There's always the chance that you're operating on stale data, which means that the next code:

```
 tdbctx.UserPermissions.SingleOrDefault(tup => tup.UserID == p.UserID);
```

Would throw as well. So every time you query the database, you'll have to write the code in such a way that it can handle the records not being present anymore.